# Code to Tell Joke if User is Between Certain Age

Tags: python-2.7

```
age = 0

joke = 'What do you call a cow with no legs? Ground beef.'

myName = raw_input('Hello! What is your name?')

myAge = raw_input('Tell me your age, ' + myName + ', to hear a joke!')

if age < 6:
    print('You are too young to hear this joke.')

elif age > 12:
    print('You are too old to hear this joke.')

elif age == range(6, 12):
    print(joke)
```

The code, when run, only says that I am too young to hear the joke even if I put a number higher than 6 or even higher than 12. Could you help me fix this problem?

Comment: How could a single number (`age`) ever be equal to a range of numbers?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the last `elif`. Just use `else` without a condition.

If both `age < 6` and `age > 12` evaluate to false, we know that 6 ≤ a ≤ 12. There's no need to check for it.

BTW, `range()` returns an *iterable*, not something you can compare with a number. The comparison will always fail because you're comparing two things that are incompatible.

Comment: myAge is also a string, not an integer, so even the non-range comparisons won't work right...

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the input into variable "myAge" and are testing variable "age" in your if statement.

Replace

```
myAge = raw_input('Tell me your age, ' + myName + ', to hear a joke!')
```

with

```
age = input('Tell me your age, ' + myName + ', to hear a joke!')
```

Comment: This is my code now: 

joke = 'What do you call a cow with no legs? Ground beef.'

myName = raw_input('Hello! What is your name?')

age = raw_input('Tell me your age, ' + myName + ', to hear a joke!')

if age < 6:
    print('You are too young to hear this joke.')
    
elif age > 12:
    print('You are too old to hear this joke.')
    
else:
    print(joke)

However, it now tells me that I'm too old for the joke even if I put in a number greater than 6. Suggestions?

Comment: raw_input() returns a string and that will make the comparison fail.
Use input() and Python will automatically (try to) convert to the correct type.

Comment: You should never use `input()`. It `eval()`s whatever the user types, which is a Horrible Idea.